# send a server a life signal from remote client

Tags: c#, signalr

I have about 300 remote computers that send data to my server. i have a windows service that i made with a console aplication which reads data from energy meters and sends alarms via email. I need to know if one of them is offline for more than one day.
the remote clients doesnt have a fixed IP address so i assume that the client would have to make the contact.
i toghut about using signalIR to send a simple messeage to the server and let it know that the client is online, but i have no idea how to do it. i also raed about helth checks but i am not sure that's what i need.

what will be the easiest way to send a short message from a client to a server?

Thank you, Shay.

Comment: If the clients already send emails, then why not just work out when the last time each client emailed a reading, and if it was >24hrs then you know which clients are offline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the clients sends email by smtp to different users and most of the days there are no alarms.

Comment: SignalR is more for a server to communicate with a Web page.  You could just write a simple web API server, and then your clients could 'ping' that server via a simple `https://yourserver.com/iamhere?id=<clientId>`

Comment: thank you Neil, if you could share a link please for an example it would be great.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-6.0